# Convergence of a Sequence - metric explanation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, convergence-divergence

I am new to functional Analysis and the way convergence of a sequence is defined confuses me . I am reading the book by Kreyzig where he says : 
A sequence ${(x_n)}$ in a metric space $X =(X,d)$ is said to converge if there is an $x \in X$ such that 
$$ \lim_{n \to \inf} d(x_{n},x) = 0$$

x is called the limit of $x_{n}$ and we write :
$$ \lim_{n \to \inf} x_{n} = x$$

Further , the author says that the metric  d yields the sequence of real numbers : $$a_{n} = d(x_{n},x)$$ whose convergence defines  that of $x_{n}$.

My Questions are
1.) When author says $x \in X$ , does it mean $x$ is a sequence ? Intuitively $x$ should be a number as it is the limit of a sequence .  BUT
2.) If $x$ is a number then how can we calculate the distance which is defined on sequences ,given that we are in a sequence space.
3.)How can the metric $d$ yield a sequence $a_{n}$ and not a number ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.) x is an element of X. If X is $\mathbb{R}$ then yes, x is just one real number.

To see why we care about $x \in \mathbb{R}$, consider if $X = (0,1)$. A sequence like $\frac{1}{n}$ will not (and should intuitively) not converge because $0$ is not in the set $X$.

2/3.) Kreyzig is just defining a new sequence $\{a_n\}$. Every metric space will have some metric d. It might be helpful to just think about this as 'distance'. How he is defining $\{a_n\}$ is by taking the distance from every point in the sequence $\{x_n\}$ and subtracting the point to which the sequence converges. See that this sequence should then converge to $0$.

Note when he writes $a_n = d(x_n, x)$ he is defining a *term* of the sequence. Hence $\{a_n\} = \{a_1, a_2,... \}$.

Comment: What If X is a  general sequence space not specifially R  ? what about x then ?

Comment: I understand that metric defines the notion of a distance . If we , for example, talk of an L-P space, then we have have a well defined metric which gives a number. But if want to talk of convergence of an element of that sequence space, we define another distance metric given in the book . is that correct ?

Comment: So I'm not sure what your book says, but it might use the p-norm. I have also seen the metric $\lim |m_n - k_n|$ for the space of Cauchy sequences over $\mathbb{Q}$. But in general, yes it definitely depends on the metric $d$ and some might define it different than others.

Answer (score 0):

SO i finally figured out what mistake i was doing .
1.) A sequence can be defined in any metric space (X,d) where X does not necessarily have to be space of sequence like the $l^{p}$ . So for the case when X is R , x wil just be a number, if X is a sequence space , the limit will indeed be a sequence.